# Find demographic of keywords

Tags: seo, keywords, analytics, demographics

I am using google keyword tool to make some research about "penang Island". There is any way to find out how people uses those keywords when there is a search? Something like which is their country or any other data like this that would help me understand who could be interested in this place and what exactly he/she wants to do there?

It seems that I cannot make myself clear, so I will try again with an example:
I would like to know from google that in the last month the searches for "penang island" came from 50% germany, 20% france, 10% UK, and so on, or another example: 30% of people looking for penang island are looking for hotels, 20% are looking for beaches and so on.

Can you give me any help on how to do that?

Comment: You manage a website about *Penang Island* without knowing what it is?

Comment: Think he/she is referring to what the site visitor wants to do on the island..

Comment: I'm not managing anything :) It's just a research, I could have said "I want to know the demographic about who searches for pizza". I simply want to know who is that searches on google for penang island

Answer (score 1):

Firts of all this question is not straight forward. I don't get what you are asking for but if you are asking if Google will tell you who searched for what as in the specific person then that is totally out of question, don't you think so?

How is it that they would distribute such information that would be infringing peoples rights. If you need to know common keyword trending as the same keyword then Google Trends would be you best option, just Google it!

Comment: I've added some examples

Comment: @Jimmy Obonyo: Please, if you don't have enough information to answer properly, comment the question first.

Answer (score 1):

Just as I said, using [Google Trends](http://www.google.com/trends/) would solve your problem. As it will show you how the keyword has been used globally and even locally. It will also give you related keywords to the keyword you are researching on.